# Automating Netlogo based on input from a spreadsheet or txt file

Tags: automation, netlogo, readfile

I have developed a model in Netlogo and i want to automate the model run.

Basically what i want to do is read the input from either an excel, csv or .txt file and then ask Netlogo to change the inputs in the model accordingly. Run the model for lets say 100 ticks and store the required output from the 100th tick onto either the same file from which the input was read-in or export it onto a different file. Something like this

```
Trial   Input1  Input2  Output
1   10  20
2   20  20  
3   10  30  
.           
.           
.           
100 20  100
```

The variables `Input 1` and `Input 2` are in the interface either as a slider or input button.

Comment: It seems you are trying to reimplement the functionality of BehaviorSpace:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html 
If not, please explain how it is inadequate to your needs.

Comment: @Alan: This is perfect. I didnt know Netlogo had such an option. I am pretty new to Netlogo. Nontheless thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Behavior space feature in Netlogo. It's available under the Tool and below is the documentation on the topic.

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html